# Flutter SQFlite many to many relationship setup

Tags: flutter, dart, many-to-many, sqflite

I have a Flutter app that will need two tables, table A and table B, **now each item from A has many items from B, and each item from B can belong to many items of A**, so it's a many-to-many relationship.

this is the code I've written:

```
static Future<Database> database() async {
    final dbPath = await sql.getDatabasesPath();
    return sql.openDatabase(path.join(dbPath, 'my_db.db'),
        onCreate: (db, version) {
      return db.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE A(id INT PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, description TEXT); CREATE TABLE B(id INT PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, description TEXT);');
    }, version: 1);
  }
```

I'm **not** doing any kind of relating the two tables to each other, because I don't know how to do that in SQFLite.

Do I need to make a third table?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First one thing you should notice is that isn't that different of using just Sql

Assuming you have **table A** and **B** you can set up as it follows

```
Future _create(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE C (
              id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
              A_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
              B_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
              FOREIGN KEY (A_id) REFERENCES A (id) 
                ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
              FOREIGN KEY (B_id) REFERENCES B (id) 
                ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
            )""");
  }
```

And you can other columns as you wish accordingly to a specific use-case